# htaccess - Forbidden page to work only via ajax or only as an include

Tags: php, .htaccess, include

I want to deny visitors access to pages but still use the pages. How can I:

~ Make a page unviewable but allow it to process ajax requests.

~ Make a PHP file unviewable but include it in scripts.

It seems I need htaccess. I tried using it but it stopped me from using the file as an include.

For the ajax only thing, it seems I can use this in the ajax-only page:

```
<?php
$AJAX = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest');
if ($AJAX){
    // echo ajax code.
}
?>
```

Is this reliable?

TAGS: only via ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish your second question about making it so a script is available for server-side inclusion and usage but not accessible from a client is to add this to an .htaccess file in the folder containing the scripts you wish to protect in this way:

```
deny from all
```

Try browsing to the script now and you should not be able to get to it. This works for the entire directory the .htaccess file is placed in.

Another way of 'shielding' the php file from access by clients through the web server like this is by placing the php files in a directory *outside* your wwwroot/public_html.

In your PHP config you'll have to add this dir to your include-search path, or simply include it via the correct relative path, or by using absolute paths.

For example, if you have root_containing_folder/wwwroot/index.php and root_containing_folder/app/core.php, in index.php you could have

```
require_once('../app/core.php');
```

and core would be included, but a browser could never get to core.php on its own. (If they could, it would have to be through a URL like www.facing-site.com/../app/core.php -- which your web server should never allow!)

Comment: And would that work for a file i run with a cron job but is forbidden from visitors.

Comment: That depends on how you run the php file as a cronjob. This sentence makes the files in the directory not visible from outside.

Comment: What are the different ways of running a cron job, as you say. Can you drop some key words on me to google. I was planning on password protecting the cron job files, by requiring a unique GET variable, and have the cron job run it with the get var. but this could be exposed to brute forcing.

Comment: Actually it couldn't be brute forced unless there's a quick way to check if the password worked.

Comment: The least invasive way to run a PHP page as a cronjob is to use lynx with the parameter --dump. This is a commandline web browser which visits the php-page so to let it run. An other way is to run php from the command line. But than php has to be installed as a cgi-addition. Don't have any experience with this. http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/running-php-scripts-with-cron/

Answer (score 1):

You can't do those things: when an script makes an AJAX request, it's the user's browser that sends the request. If you want client-side scripts to see your content, browsers must be able to see it.

You can apply some security-through-obscurity, for example by putting some kind of auth token in the script. This won't give you much protection, as all a user has to do is read the JS to get the token, but it will stop casual visitors from poking around. Your 'if XHR' is effectively doing this - a browser won't normally send that header if the address is put in the address bar, but a user can easily get the same effect outside of your AJAX code.

Comment: That makes sense, and any header read could probably be spoofed.